# Chrome extension: find element by attribute in server side page

Tags: reactjs, web-scraping, google-chrome-extension, attributes, server-side-rendering

I am developing a Chrome Extension that adds some extra functionality to the page (the page is not developed by me). I have encountered a problem on how to deal with the server-side rendered page. Basically, I want to select an item from the list in the page but the item's attributes are generated randomly (for example, not *id="myElement"* but *id="aHjfsd_elem_gtsfd"*). I think it wouldn't make sense to hardcode those random attribute names as it could change anytime. What could be the solution?

Comment: Select by a nested path or relation to other siblings e.g. using `>` and `+`, `~` combinators. You can also use attributes if there's a readable part e.g. `[id*="foo"]`

Comment: @wOxxOm The whole page has recently changed and now uses random strings for attribute names, I can't find any readable part that I can hook up. I could select by a plain text (what user sees) but I think that's not a good solution.